# I've had vs I've been having (+ I've been vs I've)

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses, sentence

What's the difference in meaning between the following 2 sentences:

- I've had a lot of problems this year
- I've been having a lot of problems this year.

Second example:

- I've been waiting for an hour
- I've waited for an hour

All four link the past to the present. Do all sentences mean the same? If not, what are the differences? The second example especially is the one that confuses me.